# class ShareGUI is not defined

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, wxpython

I recently went through a problem in my code - it can't recognize my imported class... Can you help me?? I basically just made some class to make my gui workflow a bit more productive. So for example, ButtonFrame 2 is just a class that gets the size, a static title and 2 button labels and makes the gui frame.

```
from ButtonFrame2 import *
from ShareGUI import *


class ChooseShareGUI(ButtonFrame2):
    """
    ask to have permission to take files from other
    users.
    """
    def __init__(self, username, client):
        """
        :param e: event handler
        """
        super().__init__(None, HOME_PAGE_TITLE, HOME_PAGE_TITLE + " - " + username,
                         ASK_FOR_SHARE_BTN, SHARE_BTN,
                         SYSTEM_REGISTER_PANEL_SIZE, client)
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_share)

    def on_share(self, e):
        """
        :param e: event handler
        :return: shows list of my files to share
        """
        self.Close()
        ShareGUI(self.client)
```

then, this is class ShareGUI:

```
from ChooseUserGUI import *
from GeneralGUI import *
from ReadRegistry import *
import os


class ShareGUI(GeneralGUI):
    """
    opens a window with directory dialog and a Next button
    """
    def __init__(self, client):
        """
        :param e: event handler
        """
        super().__init__(None, SHARE_TITLE, INIT_CLOUD_GUI_SIZE, client)
        self.file_to_share = None
        self.static_txt = wx.StaticText(self.pnl, label=CHOOSE_FILE_TO_SHARE)
        self.next_btn = wx.Button(self.pnl, label=NEXT_BTN)
        self.next_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_next)
        self.browser = wx.FilePickerCtrl()
        self.browser.Create(self.pnl, path=self.client.cloud, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
                            style=wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE, name=wx.DirPickerCtrlNameStr)
        self.position()
        self.Show()

    def position(self):
        """
        :return: positions everything nicely
        """
        self.sizer.Add(window=self.static_txt, proportion=PROPORTION, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, border=BORDER_SMALL)
        self.sizer.Add(window=self.browser, proportion=PROPORTION, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, border=BORDER_LARGE)
        self.sizer.Add(window=self.next_btn, proportion=PROPORTION, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 
border=BORDER_SMALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

when I run my code the error is:

```
line 38, in on_share
ShareGUI(self.client)
NameError: name 'ShareGUI' is not defined
```

please I really don't know what to do!!!

Comment: can you please try with `import ShareGui` in place of `from ShareGUI import *`?

Comment: it is because you don't imported `ShareGUI`, but all his attributes, so try `import ShareGUI`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia It just changes my error to  line 39, in on_share
    ShareGUI(self.client)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your imports, your code shown is incomplete. I always make a "minimum viable example" to boil the issue down to its essence. What you show us is frowned on (wild/starred import), but it **does** work (if your incomplete sample is broken down to what it probably looks like).

Minimum viable example, prints 'hello', in main.py:

```
from ShareGUI import *
ShareGUI()
```

and having a `ShareGUI.py` in same folder/on `PYTHONPATH`:

```
class ShareGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')
```

What you probably did on the second try:

```
import ShareGUI    
# …
ShareGUI() # -> TypeError, why do you call a module?
ShareGUI.ShareGUI() # works
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to the drawing-board with regard to your imports and how you access objects within the class, you are interested in.
A useful tool to explore what you have access to, is `dir()`.

Assume your class for import is as follows:

```
class ShareGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')
        self.client = "Myclient is alive"
```

Using the python interpreter from the command line:-

```
>>> from ShareGUI import *
>>> dir(ShareGUI)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> dir(ShareGUI())
hello
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'client']
>>> ShareGUI().client
hello
'Myclient is alive'
```

However, if we change the `import` you will get different results:-

```
>>> import ShareGUI
>>> dir(ShareGUI)
['ShareGUI', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
>>> dir(ShareGUI.ShareGUI)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> dir(ShareGUI.ShareGUI())
hello
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'client']
>>> ShareGUI.ShareGUI().client
hello
'Myclient is alive'
```

As you can see, how you do your `import`, directly affects the way you access the imported object and its components.
How you choose to import and access, is up to you but they must coincide.

N.B. with reference to one of you comments, `self.client` declares client to be an item within ShareGUI, referring to it from outside of that class, you need to drop `self` (you are not within the `ShareGUI` class). You must refer to it as a component `of` `ShareGUI`, so it's just `client`